# one of the route in routes.php defined under a namespace is not working in laravel 5.2

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-routing

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Test1', 'middleware' => 'web'], function() {
    Route::get('/instruction1', array('as' => 'instruction1', 'uses' => 'TestController1@instructionPage'));
    Route::get('/test1', array('as' => 'test1', 'uses' => 'TestController1@index'));
    Route::post('/test1/ajaxques', array('as' => 'ajaxques', 'uses' => 'TestController1@getNextQues1'));
    Route::post('/result1', array('as' => 'result1', 'uses' => 'TestController1@getResult1'));
    Route::get('/yearexam', array('as' => 'yearexam', 'uses' => 'TestController1@year'));

});
```

Here 3rd route i.e

```
Route::post('/test1/ajaxques', array('as' => 'ajaxques', 'uses' => 'TestController1@getNextQues1'));
```

is not invoking a getNextQues1 method inside the TestController1.

Comment: What exactly does it mean it's not working? Do you get any error?

Comment: I am not getting any error. There is a button in my application, when clicked it must invoke getNextQues1 method inside the TestController1, however it is not happening and as many times I click on next button I see no response.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are doing a get request but you defined a post route.

Change `Route::post` to `Route::get`